# How to show in Google Form value from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have connected Google Spreadsheet with Google Form but I don't know, how can I include values from Spreadsheet to Form and display them (which will be in my scenario free left space for course registration).

explanation picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HOotJEv18lLTNiY3ZmcGl3T3M/view?usp=sharing

Expected outcome: course has 30 free seats for students and I want to show in my Google Form, how many free seats lefts for course registration.

Many thanks for your help, also script example will be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the form in AppScript with [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) and set the questions and choices in the script. Within the script you can also reference a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), so you should be able to read the data from a spreadsheet and put it onto a form that way.

Haven't actually tried it, but it'd probably look something like:

```
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<ID>");
var val = ss.getRange(<RANGE>).getValue();

item.setTitle('Question ' + val + ' Question');
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('ONE'),
        item.createChoice('TWO'),
        item.createChoice('THREE')
    ]);
```

You can also check out this [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms-add-on) and [Video](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/327782631).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It works great but this solution seems to be static - now I have generated Form using this script with value from spreadsheet BUT when I change value in spreadsheet - generated Forms is not updated by this new value.

Am I right, that there is necessenary to "trigger" this script every time, where is this form submitted or something like that (make function with "submitting Form" trigger? Or is there better way?

Comment: Yes, it would be best to put it in a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) like `onOpen()`.